# Can I Share Sqlite Database Among iOS Apps?

Tags: database, ios, core-data, sqlite

I want to know how can i share sqlite database between two of my application.
Can i have any brilliant ideas from you guys ?

Answer (score 2):

Sandboxing in iOS won't allow files to be shared between applications. Although you could get hacky and (potentially) make something sort-of work, your best bet would be to use a web service or other outside storage to pass data between applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you wait until fall for [redacted], there might be some solutions for you. I would check the [Apple developer forums](http://devforums.apple.com) for discussions that are not covered under the NDA